# Get data from nested dynamic keys json in golang

Tags: json, go

I am new to go , I am trying to extract specific key from the json structure as below.

```
{
    "cluster_name": "escluster",
    "nodes": {
        "Sd2AvEXsswjTn6ErRYjg": {
            "timestamp": 1460624696217,
            "name": "master1",
            "transport_address": "10.0.0.1:9300",
            "host": "10.0.0.1:9300",
            "ip": [
                "10.0.0.1:9300",
                "NONE"
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "data": "false",
                "master": "true"
            },
            "os": {
                "timestamp": 1460624696217,
                "cpu_percent": 0,
                "load_average": 0,
                "mem": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 163987664,
                    "free_in_bytes": 136357264,
                    "used_in_bytes": 26629400,
                    "free_percent": 84,
                    "used_percent": 16
                },
                "swap": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 0,
                    "free_in_bytes": 0,
                    "used_in_bytes": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "yzabB-OaTfOqvgAELIMq1Q": {
            "timestamp": 1460624938213,
            "name": "data_1",
            "transport_address": "10.0.0.2:9300",
            "host": "10.0.0.2",
            "ip": [
                "10.0.0.2:9300",
                "NONE"
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "master": "false"
            },
            "os": {
                "timestamp": 1460624938213,
                "cpu_percent": 0,
                "load_average": 0.29,
                "mem": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 623840000,
                    "free_in_bytes": 4127648,
                    "used_in_bytes": 666012352,
                    "free_percent": 1,
                    "used_percent": 99
                },
                "swap": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 0,
                    "free_in_bytes": 0,
                    "used_in_bytes": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "q5CdgUF2TRewujr-0RPMgQ": {
            "timestamp": 1460624934417,
            "name": "master_0",
            "transport_address": "10.0.0.3:9300",
            "host": "10.0.0.2",
            "ip": [
                "10.0.0.3:9300",
                "NONE"
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "data": "false",
                "master": "true"
            },
            "os": {
                "timestamp": 1460624934417,
                "cpu_percent": 0,
                "load_average": 0,
                "mem": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 163898764,
                    "free_in_bytes": 139705616,
                    "used_in_bytes": 24194588,
                    "free_percent": 85,
                    "used_percent": 15
                },
                "swap": {
                    "total_in_bytes": 0,
                    "free_in_bytes": 0,
                    "used_in_bytes": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the node names are dynamic, I would like to retrieve **mem** for each node. I found [this](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-how-to-unmarshal-json-inner-nested-value-and-assign-to-specific-struct)  to retrieve data but its not dynamic key. How can we do this in go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good reference to learn how to process data in Go: http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Regarding your problem it seems to me like your data is relatively well structured... I have set an example extracting the `mem` part of each node in the following playground example:

http://play.golang.org/p/0O5U-3N_tA

The gist of it is that whatever is *strongly specified* can be encoded as `struct`s. What is dynamic (e.g. your node names) can be encoded as maps. Both can be arbitrarily intermingled, so that this:

```
type Node struct {
    Timestamp        uint64            `json:timestamp`
    Name             string            `json:name`
    TransportAddress string            `json:transport_address`
    Host             string            `json:host`
    Ip               []string          `json:ip`
    Attributes       map[string]string `json:attributes`
    Os               *OsInfo           `json:os`
}

type Payload struct {
    Name  string           `json:cluster_name`
    Nodes map[string]*Node `json:nodes`
}
```

Can capture both the general structure of a node (via its `struct` definition) and the fact that they're dynamically indexed (via the fact that nodes themselves are stored in a dynamic `map`.

Once unmarshalled, it's then trivial to process your data to extract your memory info: it's just well-known structs and maps all the way down:

```
var p Payload
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &p); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for k, node := range p.Nodes {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, node.Os.Mem)
}
```

Outputs as expected:

```
Sd2AvEXsswjTn6ErRYjg: map[total_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=163987664) free_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=136357264) used_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=26629400) free_percent:%!s(uint64=84) used_percent:%!s(uint64=16)]
yzabB-OaTfOqvgAELIMq1Q: map[used_percent:%!s(uint64=99) total_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=623840000) free_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=4127648) used_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=666012352) free_percent:%!s(uint64=1)]
q5CdgUF2TRewujr-0RPMgQ: map[total_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=163898764) free_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=139705616) used_in_bytes:%!s(uint64=24194588) free_percent:%!s(uint64=85) used_percent:%!s(uint64=15)]
```

(You are of course free to extract/reformat your data first and ditch the `Payload` object as soon as this is complete)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Saved us from reinventing the wheel. Thanks.